# RegExp match groups tag that contains specific tag

Tags: regex, xml

I need to extract ONLY the entire contents of all the  tags containing the  tag.
If this can help I post the exact opposite of the Regular Expression that I need:

- `<a>((?!<minnie>)(?:.|\n))*?<\/a>`

Example xml:

```
<a>
    <id>1</id>
    <goofy>Info</goofy>
    <trudy>Info</trudy>
</a>
<a>
    <id>2</id>
    <goofy>Info</goofy>
    <trudy>Info</trudy>
    <mickey>
        <pluto>Info</pluto>
        <minnie>Info</minnie>
    </mickey>
</a>
<a>
    <id>3</id>
    <goofy>Info</goofy>
    <trudy>Info</trudy>
</a>
<a>
    <id>4</id>
    <goofy>Info</goofy>
    <trudy>Info</trudy>
</a>
<a>
    <id>5</id>
    <goofy>Info</goofy>
    <trudy>Info</trudy>
    <mickey>
        <pluto>Info</pluto>
        <minnie>Info</minnie>
    </mickey>
</a>
<a>
    <id>6</id>
    <goofy>Info</goofy>
    <trudy>Info</trudy>
</a>
```

In this case it should extract only the `<a>` tags with id = 2 and id = 5

Comment: Why not use a XML parser?

Comment: using Regex is a requirement, at this point of the program, XML Parser or XPath are not available, only Regex is

Comment: The XML isn't well-formed, there is no outermost root element.

Comment: @MichaelKay you are right, I omitted the root element because this "xml text" is only a part of a bigger xml content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```bash
<a>(?:(?:(?!</a>).)*\n)*?\s*<minnie>(?:.*\n)+?</a>
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ji2O5b/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `<a>`: Match `<a>`
- `(?:`: Start a non-capture group

  - `(?:(?!</a>).)*`: Match 0 or of any characters as long as there is no `</a>` at next position. (This is to prevent matches across the `<a>` tags)
  - `\n`: Match a new line
- `)*?`: End non-capture group. Repeat this 0 or more times (non-greedy)
- `\s*`: Match 0 or more whitespaces
- `<minnie>`: Match `<minnie>`
- `(?:.*\n)+?`: Match 1 or more lines lazily
- `</a>`: Match `</a>`

Comment: Of course, like all attempts to parse XML using regular expressions, it is hopelessly buggy and should never be allowed into production. There are lots of places whitespace can legitimately occur, it's sensitive to the exact layout including use of newlines, it doesn't handle comments or CDATA, etc etc. You're storing up trouble for the future with this kind of solution.

Comment: @MichaelKay you are absolutely right, I know that I am putting myself in trouble with this approach but, for now, I don't have alternatives.. Maybe in future versions I can switch to XPath or something to accomplish the task